# maven run test for each classifier

Tags: maven

I have a maven war project that configure to build for multiple envs using multiple classifier. Here is how i configure the plugin for dev and test envs:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>   
   <executions>
       <execution>
       <id>package-dev</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <configuration>
           <classifier>dev</classifier>                                                         <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-dev</webappDirectory>
           <webResources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/env/dev</directory>
                </resource>
           </webResources>
       </configuration>
       <goals>
           <goal>war</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
       <id>package-test</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <configuration>
       <classifier>test</classifier>                                            <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-test</webappDirectory>
       <webResources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/env/test</directory>
          </resource>
       </webResources>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
       <goal>war</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

However, I want my test to execute on each of the classifier based on the property files that are overridden for each classifier to make sure all the test will pass in each environment. How can I do that?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: What is the test that you want to execute on each classifier?

Comment: All the tests that it execute in the default classifier. My tests are spring test which has application context xml and property files. The property files are overridden for each classifier/environment. That is why i want to make sure they are still work for all environment.

Comment: Which properties are currently used for the tests? How does Maven know to use these properties? Maybe you can configure surefire plugin to execute multiple times, as you've done for the war plugin, giving it a different path each time. But I think you're trying to force Maven into a behaviour it wasn't designed for, here.

Comment: ps It sounds like your tests are integration tests.  I'd consider splitting them into a separate project, externalising the properties, and then setting up multiple CI server tasks to run the integration tests for each set of properties.  It's good Maven practice to externalise runtime properties, at any rate.

Comment: it is not integration test. It is the same unit tests with different xml and property file for spring application context to prevent people missing overridden property file. Can you explain to me how to set surefire to execute multiple time with different path?

Comment: Seems like the surefire plugin hasn't got that option. But it does have an option to set system properties. You could use Spring's variable substitution to get the path of an import (xml or properties file) from a system property. Then you would execute surefire plugin multiple times with a different value for the system property each time. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Hope this was some help - sorry I couldn't give you a full answer.